# Can't use subplots with seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

For some reason I keep getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'subplots'
```

Does anyone know why I am getting this error?

Here is my full code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt

test_1_grades = [ 99, 90, 85, 97, 80] #data
test_2_grades = [100, 85, 60, 90, 70]

test_grades_dict = {'test 1 grades':test_1_grades,'test 2 grades':test_2_grades}#putting the data together

test_grades_data=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(test_grades_dict)#making it into a data frame so I can use seaborn

fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))#not sure if i should rename fig

axis_comp=sns.scatterplot(x='test 1 grades',
            y='test 2 grades',
            data=test_grades_data)

ax.set_xlim(min(test_2_grades)-5)#to set the same axis
ax.set_ylim(min(test_2_grades)-5)#for both x and y
```

Comment: You need to `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Answer (score 1):

You import is wrong, it should be:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have not imported pyplot

Try this instead:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```